# Apache gettext windows does not work/translate

Tags: php, windows, apache, gettext

I am new to gettext.

Here is my setup:
**/Apache 2.2
PHP 5.3.6
Windows 7/**

I have following code in the **Apache/htdocs/test/index.php**

```
<?php
    $language = 'de_DE'; 
    $translatefile = 'messages'; 
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);
    putenv("LANG=".$language); 
    bindtextdomain($translatefile, 'C:/locale'); 
    textdomain($translatefile); 

    echo gettext("Hello World!");
?>
```

I used PoEdit to generate the necessary translations under **locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/messsages.po** & messages.mo The charset I used was **UTF-8**

When I visit `http://localhost/test`, the result is Hello World! when it should be Hall Welt!

As a test, I opened command prompt and navigated to the test folder. Then I typed in

```
php index.php
```

The result that appeared in the console was

```
Hall Welt!
```

I am not sure why it is not working with Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was not solved the traditional way. I had to use the php-gettext instead of the gettext(php_gettext.dll) comes default built into php.

Details:

1) Download php-gettext from here: https://launchpad.net/php-gettext/+download
2) Add the following files in the same folder as index.php:
   - gettext.inc
   - gettext.php
   - streams.php
3) This is the new index.php

```
  <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

    // define constants
    define('PROJECT_DIR', realpath('./'));
    define('LOCALE_DIR', 'C:/locale');
    define('DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'de_DE');

    require_once('gettext.inc');

    $supported_locales = array('en_US', 'sr_CS', 'de_CH');
    $encoding = 'UTF-8';

    $locale = (isset($_GET['lang']))? $_GET['lang'] : DEFAULT_LOCALE;

    //var_dump($locale);die();

    // gettext setup
    T_setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, $locale);
    // Set the text domain as 'messages'
    $domain = 'messages';
    bindtextdomain($domain, LOCALE_DIR);
    // bind_textdomain_codeset is supported only in PHP 4.2.0+
    if (function_exists('bind_textdomain_codeset')) 
      bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, $encoding);
    textdomain($domain);

    echo gettext("Hello World!");
    ?>
```

4) Open your php.ini and comment out php_gettext.dll:

```
  ;extension=php_gettext.dll
```

visit `http://localhost/test` and you will see `Hall Welt!`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today on wampserver 2.2, apache 2.2 windows 7, 64 BITS. I unistalled it and installed 32 BITS. It works.